# Existe uma especificação REST para upload de arquivos?

Tags: json, api, rest, upload

Estou com uma dúvida a quase um mês sobre o assunto. Em determinada para do meu aplicativo, o usuário pode enviar um upload para uma biblioteca de arquivos.

Esse upload precisa ser registrando numa tabela chamada `midias`, onde, além do caminho do arquivo, preciso também de dados extras, como nome, descrição, a permissão do arquivo, além das informações de metadados como tamanho e extensão do arquivo.

A dúvida que me surge nesse caso é a seguinte: Para o registro no banco de dados referente a esse arquivo, preciso também das outras informações. E, como as requisições geralmente usam o content-type JSON, fico me perguntando como seria feito então o envio do arquivo, já que o JSON possuim certa limitação quanto aos carateres que podem ser incluidos no mesmo.

Exemplo hipotético:

```
POST /api/midias/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "nome" : "Flor",
    "descricao" : "A flor azul encontrada na 
    "tipo_acesso" : 1,
    "extensao" : "jpg",
    "tamanho"  : 5225,
    "arquivo"  : ???????
}
```

Ou seja, de acordo com exemplo acima, para criação do recurso na minha API, além das informações da mídia, precisava também de envia o binário do arquivo, para fazer o upload.

Agora vamos aos problemas:

1) A primeira forma que tentei foi enviar o binário de um arquivo via `JSON` mesmo, convertendo o binário do arquivo para `base64`.

O problema do base64 é que ele aumenta (e muito) o tamanho do arquivo, tornando inviável no meu caso, já que vamos permitir upload de vídeos.

2) Usar o `multipart/form-data`, enviando o arquivo normalmente, como se faz em requisições de formulário, e anexando os outros dados citados anteriormente num campo `"json"`, enviando esses dados como uma string `JSON` (serializado).

Exemplo:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: __atuvc=34%7C7; permanent=0; _gitlab_session=226ad8a0be43681acf38c2fab9497240; __profilin=p%3Dt; request_method=GET
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Length: 554

-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"nome" : "Flor", "descricao" : "..."}
-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Content of a.txt.

-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="a.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html><title>Content of a.html.</title>

-----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266--
```

Ao meu ver, isso foge do padrão que já está sendo usado em toda as outras requisições, que é o `content-type: application/json`, além de ser uma gambiarra das bem porcas.

3) Separar a lógica de upload do arquivo do envio dos dados da midia.

Essa me pareceu a mais agradável e, pelo pouco que li e conversei sobre, me pareceu mais organizado. Porém eu nunca fiz nada parecido, não tendo experiência de implementação, e também não sei se isso se trata de um padrão em REST.

Um das dicas que vi, por exemplo, foi fazer o upload do arquivo, retornar o `ID` desse upload, para ser utilizado no envio dos "dados extras" para criação do recurso no servidor referente a esse arquivo.

A minha dúvida é:

- Das opções acima, qual delas seria mais próxima do REST?
- Se caso seja viável implementar a terceira opção, existe algum padrão, para definir o `content-type` do arquivo e que tipo de status de resposta eu poderia devolver?

Gostaria de uns exemplos a respeito da terceira opção, já que de todas essas, foi a única que não implementei, e não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer algo parecido.

Comment: A meu ver a terceira opção pode causar um problema grave: inconsistência ou anomalia nos dados. Permitir que dados sejam cadastrados por partes tem alguns problemas, e se o dispositivo se desliga depois da primeira requisição e antes de iniciar a segunda? Como vai ser validado para que um usuário mal intencionado não cadastre diversas vezes uma parte apenas dos dados, o que pode causar alguns 404 e os usuários comuns não entenderem nada

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam mas a ideia na verdade, era criar, por exemplo, uma tabela que atribuisse o upload a um usuário. Eu retornaria o `id` desse "upload" para o usuário associá-lo ao "metadados" que precisaria ser enviado junto com o arquivo, Depois de criado os dados do recurso, moveria o arquivo no servidor para onde desejasse, já que a nova requisição informaria o `id` desse arquivo e, em seguida, deletaria o recurso do arquivo antigo criado.

Comment: Isso já tornaria o recurso mais complicado, e se ele mandar o arquivo e não passar os metadados depois? Vai ficar com um arquivo inútil no teu servidor? Vai criar uma rotina para apagar os que ultrapassam 24h? Não estou dizendo que é a pior, mas a mais complexa, talvez uma alternativa mais simples seja preferível

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida, enviar os dados json pelo body da requisição tem limite? Foge do padrão Rest?

Answer (score 7):

> Existe uma especificação REST para upload de arquivos?

Mais ou menos, [WebDAV](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), que pode ser considerado proto-REST.

> - Das opções acima, qual delas seria mais próxima do REST?

Prefiro a **opção 3**, pois facilita a vida do programador em certos aspectos. Apesar de ser a opção mais trabalhosa.

Nesse caso específico, que a API tem o papel de gerenciar o arquivo. Poderia ser feito desta maneira:

1. Requisição `POST /api/midias` para adicionar o metadado, inicializando com conteúdo de arquivo vazio. Sendo **request** `Content-Type: application/json`, **response** `Content-Type: application/json`.
2. Requisição `POST /api/midias/1/conteudo` para adicionar o conteúdo do arquivo. Sendo **request** `Content-Type:` ver resposta abaixo, **response** `Content-Type: application/json`. O número 1 significa o ID da mídia.

Assim, o download do arquivo em si, seria através de `GET /api/midias/1/conteudo`, e `GET /api/midias/1` para consultar metadados.

---

> - Se caso seja viável implementar a terceira opção, existe algum padrão,
>     para definir o content-type do arquivo e que tipo de status de
>     resposta eu poderia devolver?

Para `/api/midias/1/conteudo` usaria `multipart/form-data` ou/e `application/octet-stream`(que é mais simples). Mas se o arquivo tem o próprio tipo MIME, vale a tentativa (pode complicar a configuração do CORS depois). Retorne o status do mesmo jeito que as suas outras APIs. Se é `200` para sucesso, e `400` para erro, por que seria diferente neste caso?

Answer (score 7):

Resposta resumida: *não*.
O HTTP suporta upload direto, e o REST especifica URLs - isso é o que vai ficar mais perto.

Quanto as suas opções,talvez o mais interessante aí seja algo que fica parecido com sua terceira opção, mas na ordem inversa: 
você faz um POST JSON com os metadados do arquivo - nome, e tamanho, inclusive - e recebe, na resposta, uma URL que pode ser usada para upload do arquivo completo.

O Upload, por sua vez, você faz como um post de HTTP do arquivo - não precisa ser multi-part encoded - você pode simplesmente enviar os cabeçalhos de http normais -

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: XXXX
```

seguido do seu arquivo - todo o "corpo" da mensagem HTTP vai ser o conteúdo do arquivo. Esse método ainda tem outra vantagen - faz tempo que não visito as especificações do HTTP, mas acredito que seja possível colocar no cabeçalho que você está "continuando um request anterior" e um "offset" - e portanto, mandar um arquivo grande, como um arquivo de vídeo, em vário requests separados - retransmitindo os que falharem.

Você não mencionou qual linguagem/framework está usando do lado do servidor, mas acredito que a grande maioria permita que você possa ter uma view mais "baixo nível" que interprete os cabeçalhos e o copo do HTTP elas mesmas. A URL em si já vai incluir um token que você relaciona no banco com a postagem JSON anterior - então sabe: a que o arquivo está relacionado, e se a pessoa usando esse endereço tem autorização pra isso (basta que seja um token randomizado na URL- ele vai servir ao mesmo tempo de identificador e autorização para o arquivo).

Eu tinha começado a escrever esta resposta - fui fazer uma busca rápida pra confirmar se posts HTTP com um arquivo puro são permitidos, e acabei chegando num artigo sobre uploads com REST - e o autor fez mais ou menos as mesmas considerações que fiz aqui - ou seja, parece ser um caminho sensato. (E que ainda permite upgrades futuros tipo - a feature de quebrar o arquivo em partes e fazer uploads de segmentos não precisa ser implementada num primeiro momento).

O artigo: https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2016/01/04/http-rest-api-file-uploads/