# Utilização do input file com JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Boa tarde a todos, estou criando uma tela de cadastro e estou com uma dúvida referente ao `<input type="file">` (File esse que será 100% dos casos uma imagem, sem necessidade de validação). Gostaria de realizar o cadastro e passar o mesmo para uma outra tela, utilizando apenas JS, mas não entendi muito bem como eu posso salvar essa imagem em um JSON, visto que eu só conseguiria fazer isso se fosse uma URL (certo?). Alguém tem alguma dica do que posso fazer?

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338010, talvez  até seja o que quer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que colocar essa imagem num buffer.

Inputs do tipo `file` só captura metadados do arquivo (incluindo a URI que você vê no `value`). O arquivo (binário) em si só é lido por completo quando você o envia por meio de um `submit`, ou então você pode utilizar JavaScript para obter tais dados.

Com JavaScript você pode utilizar a classe `FileReader` para ler esse arquivo. No exemplo abaixo, o valor binário do arquivo é convertido para base64, para aliviar na quantidade de carga que precisará ser transmitida, basicamente uma compactação.

```
const meuImput = document.getElementById('id_do_input');
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(meuImput.files[0]);
reader.onload = function () {
  // Aqui temos a sua imagem convertida em string em base64.
  console.log(reader.result);
};
```

Comment: Entendi! E ai no caso de descompactar como eu faria?

Comment: Se você for descompactar no back-end, vai depender da linguagem. Se você for descompactar no front... provavelmente não será necessário. Você pode utilizar a string como `src` de uma `img`, em base64 mesmo, e irá funcionar normalmente.